# Google Map API3 return no map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to make marker on google map, based on adress, but maps is showing no data?

Here is my example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* google maps */

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14, // set the zoom level manually
        zoomControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var address = $('#map').text(); /* change the map-input to your address */
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: address,
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map,
                            title: address
                        });

                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


});
```

**HTML**

```html
<p id="map">
          Vojvode Dobrnjca, Belgrade
              </p>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Your code works for me, how/where do you load the maps-API and jQuery?

Comment: Your map works for me with CSS that gives the map a size [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x2karr4g/1/).  If that isn't the problem, please provide a [Minimal, **Complete, Tested** and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You had missed `center` in `mapOptions`.
And you should create `geocoder` variable in `initialize` function.
Please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qcfneg5b/). I had shown your map.